# Getting shapefile name with ArcPy code?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, python-script-tool

Using the FeatureToPoint tool I've having difficulty calling just the name for the shapefile without the extension or path. Here is the part of the script that I'm creating that I am stuck on.

eg. `C:\user\shapefiles\polygon.shp` I just want the word `polygon`

```py
import arcpy

file1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # this is a .shp file 
savepointlocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

arcpy.FeatureToPoint_management(file1, save1, "INSIDE")
```

The problem is that its calling for the path of `C:\user\shapefiles\polygon.shp` and not just the name `polygon`.

I'm new and I'm sure there is some function or way to just call the name of the file without the path or the .shp in the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using 2 [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) functions (splitext and basename):

```
import os
os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(r'C:\user\shapefiles\polygon.shp'))[0] # returns 'polygon'
```